Is there Maamar Tekhiyat HaMetim from the Rambam online version in English?
BH
Hi, do they have Maamar Techiyat HaMeitim by the Rambam somewhere online?
This is the Hebrew version https://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam%2C_Maamar_Tekhiyat_HaMetim.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
Although if there is an English translation what is the website for it?

Yes, you can find an English translation here. The translation is part of the book "Maimonides - Crisis And Leadership" by Avraham   Halkin and David Hartman and includes translations of some Rambam's key epistles, one of them being Iggeret Techiyat Ha'metim. The book in its entirety is available for free online via the link.
